# Converting from binary to hex and back

Tags: embedded, busybox, hexdump

Given a binary file, how do you convert it to a hex string and back, using only standard tools like `sed` and `cut`, on a minimal system with `busybox` installed?

These tools are **not** available:

- `perl`
- `python`
- `xxd` (comes with vim)
- `gcc`

A `hexdump` command comes with `busybox`, but it is different from the one that comes with `util-linux`.

I'm looking for a script or command to convert a file to a hex string, and a corresponding one for converting it back to binary. The intermediate format doesn't have to be hex, it can be base64 or something else.

This is for an embedded device with limited disk space.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to? What constraints are there on the string, does it just have to be printable?

Comment: It's for an old system, for copying a file over telnet in an expect script, for debugging. The string does not have to be printable, but it's an advantage that it doesn't have to be escaped when using expect. (I know, I know, telnet is pretty bad. Luckily, it was removed in all later versions).

Comment: OK, so mostly need to avoid control characters. Do you know what version of busybox you have?

Comment: Yes, 1.18.4 (quite old) or 1.26.2 (the latest version).

Comment: From the source, it looks like 1.18.4 should have both `uuencode` and `makemime`. Are they not available?

Comment: They are possible to add, but for reasons that are out of my hands, they will not be added. The idea is that fewer available tools increases the security of the system. They could be added just for debugging, but the idea is to use this also for older systems where it's not possible / very hard to add debug tools.

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I came up with (based on several online sources and some experimentation).

### Converting from hex to bin (`hex2bin`):

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' "$1" | xargs printf
```

### Converting from bin to hex (`bin2hex`):

```
#!/bin/sh
hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' "$1"
```

### Example use:

```
./bin2hex binary_file_1 | ./hex2bin - > binary_file_2
diff -s binary_file_1 binary_file_2
```

This works with busybox, but hex2bin is unfortunately limited by the maximum length of the argument given to `xargs`, so this method will only work for small files (less than 32 KiB on my desktop system).

Comment: Rumors are there is such a thing as [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Thanks, removed `cat` frrom `bin2hex`. When using `sed -i` instead of `cat` and `sed`, however, `sed` complained that it could not read `-` (while `cat` had no such complaint).

Comment: @Alexander, `-i` tries to edit in place, which is hard to do for a stream. You can still do without the cat and use `sed < "$1" 's/...'" | ...`

Comment: @ilkkachu, with `sed < "$1" ...`, using `-` as the filename does not work. I get `line 2: -: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Alexander, ah yes, I missed you wanted that. Though of course you could explicitly test `$1` against a dash but of course it's easier since `cat` has the logic built-in.

Comment: Note that `printf '\xHH'` is not standard. `printf '\OOO'` with octal code is standard though.

Comment: Couldn't bin2hex simply be `hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' "$1"`

Comment: @jbo5112 Thanks! That works great on BusyBox 1.31.1. I'll test with BusyBox 1.18 as well, but I assume it works. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly (and only using a common subset compatible with `busybox` (or at least the `busybox` as built for the current `busybox` Debian package):

- `bin2hex`:

  ```
  (
    export LC_ALL=C
      od -An -vtx1 |
      tr -s ' \t\n' '\n\n\n' |
      grep .
  )
  ```

  (one hex per line)
- `hex2bin`:

  ```
  (
    export LC_ALL=C
      awk '
        BEGIN{
          for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            c[sprintf("%02x", i)] = sprintf("%o", i)
        }
        NR % 200 == 1 {printf "%s", end "printf '\''"; end = "'\''\n"}
        {printf "\\%s", c[$0]}
        END {print end}' |
      sh
  )
  ```

If your `busybox`, contrary to Debian's one has been built without the *DESKTOP* option, then the `-An` and `-tx1` option to `od` won't be available. You can use `od -b` instead which will give a one-byte octal dump with octal offsets. `od -b` is Unix but not POSIX however so won't work on every Unix-like system.

`bin2hex` would become:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
    od -b |
    awk '
      BEGIN{
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
          hex[sprintf("%03o", i)] = sprintf("%02x", i)
      }
      NF > 1 {for (i = 2; i<= NF; i++) print hex[$i]}'
)
```

Again, tested only with Debian's busybox, I can't tell how much of that is dependant on some `busybox` compile-time option or another. You'd have to test on the target system.

Comment: When running this `bin2hex` script on the hardware device, I get:

```
od: invalid option -- 'A'
BusyBox v1.26.2 (2017-03-13 14:50:51 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [FILE]

Print FILE (or stdin) unambiguously, as octal bytes by default
```

I get the same result on my desktop system.

Comment: @Alexander, yes, as always with busybox, how much of the POSIX standard is implemented depends very much on the version and the selected configuration options at build time. Here, for it to support `od -A`, it seems you need to tick the `DESKTOP` option (_"Enable options for full-blown desktop systems"_) at build time (as is done with my Debian busybox it would seem). You can always leave out the `-An` and filter out the address with `sed`, but it looks like it would still not support `-tx1`, so you're probably out of luck with your busybox `od`. Or you'd need awk again to translate oct to hex

Comment: @Alexander, see edit if the alternative works on your target system.

Comment: The new version seems to freeze on my desktop system (64-bit Arch Linux, busybox 1.26.2). On the test hardware with the new version of busybox (1.26.2) it also times out and produces no output. I'm not well versed enough in `awk` to see why. `od -b` works as expected. busybox `awk` is present. Same result with busybox 1.18.4.

Comment: @Alexander, are you feeding the output on stdin (of that subshell, as in `(...) < file`)?

Comment: No, that was my mistake. Works perfectly now!

Comment: @Alexander. Testing with the Arch boot cd, /usr/lib/initcpio/busybox doesn't have the `od` applet but it does have `hexdump -b` which gives the same output as `od -b` (`hexdump` is neither a POSIX nor Unix standard command)

Answer (score 3):

Your busybox may have been built with the applet **base64** so you could do

```
busybox base64 <bin >txt
busybox base64 -d <txt >bin
```

Or if not you may have the venerable **uuencode** and **uudecode**, which may also have the `-m` option to encode in hex. Eg

```
echo -n abcABC | busybox uuencode -m - | busybox uudecode -
```

List the built-in applets with `busybox --list`.

Comment: Thanks! `base64` and `uuencode` are unfortunately not available on the hardware device, but it works great on my desktop system.

Comment: how does the base64 convert to hex?

Comment: @TheFool It doesn't convert to hex, but the questioner also said: *The intermediate format doesn't have to be hex, it can be base64 or something else*, and so this base64 program is a solution.